# Запятая перед тире после вводного слова

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая перед тире, после вводных слов "по моему мнению"?

Самое главное наше достижение, по моему мнению, - это создание и развитие замечательного коллектива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно, нужны и запятая, и тире. Уж запятая точно.

Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым не ставится, если между ними стоит вводное слово (а также наречие, союз, частица), но в данном примере имеется ЭТО, перед ЭТО тире ставится всегда.

Comment: Спасибо. Уже нашла информацию в интернете: http://otvet.mail.ru/question/78002867